# пустая строка в таблице html

Tags: html

Как сделать одну строку в таблице html пустой, чтобы она была в качестве разделителя?

Comment: что именно у вас не получилось? если она нулевой высоты, задайте ее явно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

В атрибуте `colspan` указывается количество колонок для объединения.

Comment: У вас все строки не отличаются содержанием :)